# CoreData object is nil after saving context with merge policy

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a main context and a background one, both of them have the `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` and `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` set to `true`.

The entity has a `constraint` on the `id` property of the entity.

I create and save new objects on the `backgroundContext`.

Now, the first I create and save the object, after the saving I can read the object directly.

```swift
let object= Object(context: .background)
// [... object configuration]

PersistenceController.shared.saveContext(.background) // No merging since no other objects has the same `id`

// And here I CAN read the `object` like this:
object.name // Test name
```

Then if I save another object with the same `id`, CoreData detects a conflict and merges the two object, and that's correct.
But I am not able to access the object like earlier.

```swift
let object= Object(context: .background)
// [... object configuration]

PersistenceController.shared.saveContext(.background) // Merging occurs

// And now I CANNOT read the `object`. It has all properties nil.
object.name // nil
```

I tried also fetching by ObjectID but the result is the same.

What is happening? How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this a problem with your persisted data or in the debugger?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the data are persisted and merged correctly

Comment: Then is this a real problem? I guess Core Data invalidates the objects in memory that has been changed in a merge, maybe you could check the state of the object.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, this is a bit of a problem, since I fetch data from API. If Between fetching and saving I lose the data I should try to retrieve them from CoreData, but with Arrays of data is not that easy

Comment: So you are keeping your background context alive and reuses it? What about reloading the object using [existingObject(with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506686-existingobject), could that work?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It returns `nil`. I think because CoreData keeps the original object ID and not the merged one.

Comment: So maybe you should remove your background context once you have merged and create a new one for your next api call.

Comment: Another option is to listen to the notifications sent from NSManagedObjectContext, perhaps [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/3618796-nsmanagedobjectcontextdidmergech)